# v1.6.0 - CreateShipment SOAP v2 call ships all items

Tags: api, magento-1.6, shipment

We want to update orders with shipment details from an external system. We have successfully done the basics, but need to be able to partially ship orders.

The API description appears to allow for this, http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html and specfically:

**Notes:** The array of orderItemQty is used for partial shipment. To create shipment for all order items, you do not need to specify these attributes.

However the API appears to ignore this. It doesn't seem to matter if we populate it with all the items and 0 out the ones we don't want shipped or just exclude them entirely.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or had to create partial shipments via the API before?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code you currently use to create the shipment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api_V2` class you should use the following format for the itemsQty array (as in the WS-I compliance mode example):

```
array('order_item_id' => '8', 'qty' => '1');
```

If the array is missing the keys `order_item_id` or `qty` it will ignore the specified rows in the function `_prepareItemQtyData` and when all rows are skipped the API will ship all items.

Comment: Just a note on this. We are using 1.6.0 and WS-I compliance is off. It would appear the Magento documentation is out of step with the code. Thanks for the info.